# GCP cloud sql postgres connection count missing

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a problem after migration postgres instance from 9 to 12, we were following this method https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/upgrade-db.

Before migration, I had a graph whit active connections on instance page and after the migration (on the new instance - postgres 12) - I don`t have values on this graph.

I am receiving a message like "No data is available for the selected time frame."

Also if  I am run a query like "SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;"
I see the number of connections.

Answer (score 3):

At this moment the graph section for connections count in Postgres12 is not currently supported. The Cloud SQL engineering team is working on implementing this feature as its already implemented for other Postgres versions. This is not just happening to you, it is a general behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to report an issue is to use a [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0)[1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0), where you can share your project information.

I found that same error reported by another client but I cannot relate it to your scenario.